# Big List Request Of Comparisons To The 2019 College Admissions Bribery Scandal

Tags: university

Dear academics and scholars,

Since the primary purpose of the Stackexchange academic community is suppose to be creating a reliable internet resource of easy to access facts;  this "Big List" request for similar cases from around the world should, in my humble opinion, be "compelling" enough to be expanded upon.

> Questions asking for a "big list" of examples, illustrations, etc. Ask only when the topic is compelling, and please do not use this as the only tag for a question.

Recently, in the US;  the [**"largest-ever"**](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/2019_college_admissions_bribery_scandal) college admissions bribery scandal was exposed in the news.

> "The case is the largest of its kind to be prosecuted by the US Justice Department.[14]"

How does the scale and scope of this particular  case compare with these types of scandals in college admissions exams in other "third-world" and European countries?

Comment: Without a lot more detail this is hard to say. First, we don't know how you want to compare them. Second, determining how common anything like this is anywhere is very difficult. This scandal itself only came to light due to a somewhat convoluted set of circumstances. Actually telling how common something is is not easy. Also, cultural differences may be relevant: what is bribery in one culture may be not treated as bribery in another.

Comment: It may not be the largest -  as others may not have been caught yet... Typical journalist hype...

Comment: How does what compare?

Comment: One thing that you seem not to realize by insisting with this question is that around the world, in particularly in Europe, there's almost no "college-culture" as in the US. In particular, most of the universities have low-admission barriers because many countries think that education is an investment for the country. This essentially means that most of the sufficiently motivated students actually enter in their university of choice and, moreover, the entrance fees are reasonably low. Why would anyone want to bribe in such conditions?

Answer (score 5):

Oh boy, this was so cute when they mentioned it was the biggest scandal in the US history. It happens around the world more frequently and at a larger scale. [Here is a brief summary of these kinds of scandals around the world](https://www.washingtonpost.com/opinions/2019/03/16/our-big-college-admissions-scandal-just-made-us-look-lot-more-like-rest-world/?noredirect=on&utm_term=.8a2cd0973463).

Here are a couple from my home country of India. This one was at a large scale in the state of Madhya Pradesh called [Vyapam scam](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vyapam_scam). It was big enough that they made a wiki page for this. I remember it was in the news for too long when it happened. "It involved scamsters including politicians, senior and junior officials and businessmen systematically employing imposters to write papers, manipulate exam hall seating arrangements and supply forged answer sheets by bribing officials." Wikipedia

Another one from same Indian state called Dental and Medical Admission Test [(DMAT scam)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DMAT_scam).

Comment: "biggest scandal in the US history" *of its kind*. I'm pretty sure Watergate was a bigger scandal.

Answer (score 1):

Many universities accept all students who apply.  At these institutions, nobody pays a bribe to be admitted to the university.

Comment: we call it a "fee" instead.